# Reference index / home / main view in framework7 vue simple project for route '/'

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I've create a project based on: https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-template-vue-simple...

I need to be able to navigate back to the home / main view after navigating several sub-views deep...  It's definitely attempting to navigate to `/` when I hit back on the penultimate item in the back stack and advice I've had on the issue I raised (https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-template-vue-simple/issues/7), is to reference the Home / main view component for the route `/`.

My Vue / Framework7 app is intialised with:

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: function () {
    return {
        // Framework7 parameters here
        f7params: {
            root: '#app', // App root element
            id: 'io.framework7.testapp', // App bundle ID
            name: 'Framework7', // App name
            theme: 'md', // Automatic theme detection,
            stackPages: true,
            domCache: true,
            // App routes,
            routes: [
            {
                path: '/submenu/category/:categoryId/',
                component: 'ym-submenu',
            }, {
                path: '/submenu/menuitem/:menuitemId/',
                component: 'ym-submenu',
            }, {
                path: '/',
                component: 'app'
            }]
        },
        rootAreas: [],
        categories: [],
        news: [],
        searchResults: [],
        submenuContent: []
    };
},
created: function () {
    console.log('Created Main App');
    documentReady();
    this.$on('rootmapsUpdated', function (arg) {
        this.rootAreas = arg;
    });
    this.$on('categoriesUpdated', function (arg) {
        this.categories = arg;
    });
    this.$on('newsUpdated', function (arg) {
        this.news = arg;
    });
    this.$on('searchResultsUpdated', function (arg) {
        this.searchResults = arg;
    });
    this.$on('submenuContentUpdated', function (arg) {
        this.submenuContent = arg;
    });
}
});
```

I have no idea how to achieve this though...
I have tried creating a component pointing to #app

```
Vue.component('app', {
    template: '#app'
});
```

and routing to it using:

```
routes: [{
        path: '/',
        component: 'app'
},
...
```

I've also tried putting `this` as the component and assigning the result of `new Vue()` to a global variable and putting that as the component. I've also  tried routing to `index.html` using `url:` instead of `component:` and similarly `templateUrl:`...

Nothing I have tried has worked... Any hints / ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to keep my main view empty, but to route the content to a component made up of what used to be my main view using a `url="/"` argument to the `<f7-view>` tag e.g.

```
<div id="app">
    <f7-app :params="f7params">
        <f7-view id="main-view" main url="/"></f7-view>
    </f7-app>
</div>

<template id="page-home">
    <f7-page>
        <f7-navbar>
            <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
                <div class="header-logo-container"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"></div>
                <div class="left back-btn"><a href="#" class="link icon-only invisible"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></div>
                <div class="right settings-btn"><a href="#" class="link icon-only"><i class="material-icons">settings</i></a></div>
            </div>
        </f7-navbar>
        <f7-toolbar class="tabbar solid">
            <ym-toolbar></ym-toolbar>
        </f7-toolbar>
        <ym-toplevelitems></ym-toplevelitems>
    </f7-page>
</template>
```

Then add a route for "/" to the new page-home component...

```
routes: [ ...
            {
                path: '/',
                component: 'page-home'
            }]

...


Vue.component('page-home', {
    template: '#page-home'
});
```

Now navigating to / yields the same thing as entering the app :D